# pickle/zodb: how to handle moving .py files with class definitions?

Tags: python, refactoring, pickle, zodb

I'm using `ZODB` which, as I understand it, uses `pickle` to store class instances. I'm doing a bit of refactoring where I want to split my `models.py` file into several files. However, if I do this, I don't think `pickle` will be able to find the class definitions, and thus won't be able to load the objects that I already have stored in the database. What's the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create aliases; because one `models.py` modules is being split into multiple new modules you can only do this by importing your classes into the old location.

Both methods cause new copies of your instance pickles to refer to the new location; if you can force a write on *all* instances of the moved classes you don't need to retain the aliases. You can do this by setting `_p_changed` to `True` on your instances that you want to be written again.

So, to create the aliases, import your moved classes in the old location:

```
from newmodule1 import MyClass1, MyClass2
from newmodule2 import MyClass3
```

If you only *rename* a module (so the same classes all are found in one new location, could be a set of imports themselves), you can also create a `sys.modules` entry for the old name:

```
import sys
import newmodule

sys.modules['full.path.to.old.module] = newmodule
```

Comment: ah, this seems to be what I want. So pickle, when loading the existing instances, will look in the old `models.py`, find the classname, and load the class properly, but the loaded class will actually be in the new location... clever

Comment: @Claudiu: Exactly, so when writing a new pickle for the class, it'll use the new module path.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you want to make the pickle loadable without performing a migration to the new class model structure: you can use alias imports of the refactored classes inside the location of the old model.py.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy solution. You can convert your old-style objects with the refactored ones (I mean classes which are in another file/module) by the following schema

1. add the refactored classes to your code *without* removing the old-ones
2. walk through your DB starting from the root and replacing *all* old objects with new equivalents
3. compress your database (that's important)
4. now you can remove your old classes from the sources

Comment: aye i was hoping to not have to do something like that. the alias solution seems promising...

Comment: @Claudiu I don't like the aliasing solution since it brings mess in code. But it works of course :-)